# Will the RosSerial client reconnect?

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will the rosserial client, in particular, rosserial_arduino, reconnect and republish topics if it loses its connection to the master?

For my use case, it would be nice if my Arduino would reconnect automatically when I restart ROS on my computer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11131/will-the-rosserial-client-reconnect?/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2011-09-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosserial_python node will automatically resync topics with the Arduino whenever it A) starts up, or B) decides the connection has failed. This is currently done by using the ros::Time synchronization call as a keep alive, if no calls show up in a given time, the connection is restarted (this can take up to 5-10s currently).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3